# Using Redemption to get message from ID in Outlook causes system error code 18 there are no more files

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I found a computer that, if I call `RDOSession.GetMessageFromID` in my Outlook add-in, it throws a `COMException` saying "System Error. Code: 18. There are no more files".

I have tried the following but the problem persisted:

- Reinstall Office 365 32-bit
- Deleted the profile from Outlook and recreated one, added the Office 365 exchange account to Outlook again to make sure a new data file was created
- Updated Redemption to the latest version 5.17.0.5062

I have tested this on another computer with the exact same exchange account, and same Outlook version, the problem did not happen.

Does anyone know what else I can do to resolve this problem, other than maybe reinstalling the entire Windows OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem in the insider build of Windows 10 due to a missing system resource file (it stores TZ info). It will be fixed in the upcoming version of Redemption (5.18).

Send an email to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com to receive an updated version of the library.